# Google Sheets API Node.js Append Overwrite

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dumb question. I have a script running on google sheets. Every week, I would like to run a script and replace the data on a specific sheets.

I tried to do it through insertDataOption = OVERWRITE, but it does not work.

When I read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#InsertDataOption), here what is written:

> **OVERWRITE** The new data overwrites existing data in the areas it is written. (Note: adding data to the end of the sheet will still insert new rows or columns so the data can be written.)

Do you have any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Hello! Could you please provide the code you are using for inserting the data in your Sheets so that we can better understand the context of the question? Cheers

Comment: Can you confirm that you provided a `range` as well when performing the request? For example, if you want to overwrite the row A2, you should provide a range = A1 (append insert data after the last row of the range).

Comment: @Frenchcooc Sorry for the late answer I was in holidays! See my code below

Comment: Hey @kevrabe were you able to solve your issue with my answer? Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it in case it was useful to you. Otherwise, kindly describe the issue you are having,  so we may help you. Cheers

Comment: @carlesgg97 sorry for not answering, yes I solved it and thank you so much about your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [`spreadsheets.values.append`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) endpoint. From the documentation:

> **Appends** values to a spreadsheet. The input range is used to search for existing data and find a "table" within that range. Values will be appended to the next row of the table, starting with the first column of the table.

If what you want, instead of appending data is to replace data in a range of your sheet, you should instead be using the [`spreadsheets.values.update`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) endpoint. For your case, it can be used as follows:

```js
function insertData(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
  var request = {
      spreadsheetId: '###',
      range: 'A1:D48',
      valueInputOption: 'RAW',
      resource: {
          values: [[getting_company_name, duration_event, current_date, getting_profesional_service]]
      }
  };
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(request,
   (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
  });
}
```

You can find more information on creating a node js application for Sheets [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs)

Answer (score -1):

@Frenchcooc

```
 var request = {
    // The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
    spreadsheetId: '###',
    range: 'A1:D48', 
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    insertDataOption: 'OVERWRITE',
    resource: {
        values: [[getting_company_name, duration_event, current_date, getting_profesional_service]]
    },
    auth: authClient,
};
```